# mysql_fetch_array convert into mysqli_

Tags: mysql

Im trying to rewrite mysql_ into mysqli_, but got 2 errors

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

and

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,

why? Ive fixed `mysql_query("SELECT...)` into `mysqli_query($db, "SELECT..)` and all others

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include('config/configuration.php'); 

if($_POST['Login'])
 {
  $UserName=$_POST['username'];
  $Password=md5($_POST['password']); 

  $UserQuery=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT Id, UserName, FirstName, LastName, Level FROM users WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password' AND IsActive=1 and level >= 3");

    $UserDetails=mysqli_fetch_array($UserQuery);        

        if(mysqli_num_rows($UserQuery))
            {       
                    $_SESSION['UserName'] = $UserDetails['UserName'] . ' (' .  $UserDetails['FirstName'] . ' ' . $UserDetails['LastName'] . ')';
                    $_SESSION['UserId'] = $UserDetails['Id'];
                    $_SESSION['Level']  = $UserDetails['Level'];

                mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET NumberOfLogin = NumberOfLogin + 1, LastLoginDate = NOW() WHERE Id = " . $_SESSION['UserId'] . " ");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-selec)

Comment: I think its ok
     `$db = mysqli_connect($host, $db_user, $db_password, $database);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your query is failing.

Try this to see the issue:

```
if (!$UserQuery) {
    echo "MySQLi Error: " . mysqli_error($con);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the query failed, thanks to you I've managed to fix it.
Thank you very much again.


The problem was I didnt noticed, that database contain `Id, UserName, Level`, but no `FirstName and LastName`.